# How to type React Hook Form control prop in reusable component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I have a reusable form. This form can have different inputs depending on where it is used. I pass `control` as prop to this form from parent component (which holds all the logic) with type `any` but I'd like to have a more strict typing. How to do this?

I mean in one component an input can be like `{name: ""}` and another `{face: "", address: ""}` so how to type control prop in CreateForm so that it works with different inputs?

Parent component which holds the input logic:

```
type CreateFaceInput = {
      name: string;
      cover: string;
    };
    
const FaceModal = ({ open, onClose }: IFaceModalProps) => {

  const {
    handleSubmit,
    control,
  } = useForm<CreateFaceInput>({
    defaultValues: {
      name: '',
      cover: '',
    },
  });

  const onSubmit = (data: CreateFaceInput) => {};

  return (

          <CreateForm
            onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
            control={control}
          />
        )
  );
};
```

**CreateForm.tsx**

```
import { Controller } from 'react-hook-form';

interface ICreateFormProps {
  control: any;
  onSubmit: () => void; 
}

const CreateForm = ({ onSubmit, control }: ICreateFormProps) => {


  return (
      <Controller
        render={({ field, fieldState: { error } }) => (
          <StyledTextField
            {...field}
          />
        )}
        control={control}
      />
  );
};
```

aaaa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can add `FieldValues` type

```
import { Control, FieldValues } from "react-hook-form";


interface ICreateFormProps {
     control:?: Control<FieldValues, CreateFaceInput>;
```

Comment: It was an example for one form. Say, I will have 10 different forms then it shoud be like this? control:?: Control<FieldValues, FistFormInput, SecondFormInput ... and so on>;

Comment: you can make the component generic. like this `interface ICreateFormProps <T> {
     control:?: Control<FieldValues, T>;`

Comment: I'm sorry but one more question...what should I write here if I will will use generic (it requires 1 arg)? const CreateForm = ({ onSubmit, control }: ICreateFormProps<???>)

Comment: the type, like  `({ onSubmit, control }: ICreateFormProps<FistFormInput>`

Comment: And what is the difference between generic option and Control<FieldValues, FirstFormInput> if I should list all inputs? Looks the same

Comment: can use different type depend on the form ` ICreateFormProps<FistFormInput>` or ` ICreateFormProps<SecondFormInput>` and so on